# How do you load an image on VSC for Python

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread('25.png')
plt.imshow(image)
```

I've used this code here to try and produce the image but it keeps saying that the module does not exist.

Comment: sounds like you don't have matplotlib installed in the python environmental that VSCode is using

Comment: I dont know what the extension is called

Answer (score 0):

First, you should import 'matplotlib.pyplot'
Second, make sure the photo is in the same directory as your code is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread('25.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: Both programme and picture/image are both in the same directory, i knew that part, but he terminal keeps saying that there's no name for a module called it and i dont know what extension to get